# Receber quantidade indefinida de parâmetros em C#

Tags: c#, parâmetros

O método `Main(string[] args)` recebe um array de parâmetros de quantidade indefinida. Mas sei que isso não funciona em um método comum. Como se cria um método que receba quantos parâmetros forem necessários?

Comment: Há um equívoco na sua pergunta, se não fosse possível como a função `Main` o faria? A resposta do @Lucas Nunes está correta, mas é possível fazer das duas maneiras. Existe uma diferença de própositos entre receber uma array de tamanho indeterminado e receber uma quantidade indeterminada de parâmetros.

Comment: @Cahe Editei a resposta acrescentando alguns detalhes. No caso, o `Main` já recebe um `string[]` devidamente tratado enquanto os métodos com `params` tem os argumentos convertidas em tempo de compilação para algo do tipo `new int[] {1,2,3}`, e funcionam como um `int[]` normal.

Comment: Meu propósito é simples: dar liberdade ao usuário de informar quantos valores ele quiser somar, ou multiplicar, por exemplo. `params`, como ensinado pelo @Lucas Nunes, parece ser o mais correto, mas se houver outras formas, por favor apresente como resposta ou mesmo comentário. O importante é nós aprendermos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso utilizando a palavra-chave `params`.
Com ela você define um parâmetro que utiliza vários argumentos ou nenhum.

Por exemplo:

```
    private static int Somar(params int[] values)
    {
        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            sum += values[i];
        }

        return sum;
    }
```

E, com isso, você pode chamar as `Somar()` da seguinte forma:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("O resultado da soma é " + Somar(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
        Console.WriteLine("Outro resultado da soma é " + Somar(10, 20, 4));
        Console.WriteLine("Quando não soma nada é " + Somar());

        Console.Read();
    }
```

---

Deve-se ressaltar que o parâmetro com `params` deve ser o último na função. Por exemplo:

```
// A seguite declaração é inválida:
private static void Imprimir(params int[] valores, string titulo) { }

// Já essa é válida (pois params vai por último):
private static void Imprimir(string titulo, params int[] valores) { }
```

---

Outro detalha importante é que o compilador dará prioridade para a versão especializada do método (se esse existir).

Por exemplo, se você tem os seguintes métodos definidos:

```
private static int Somar(int a, int b) { }
private static int Somar(params int[] values) { }
```

e chamar `Somar(10, 20)`, o compilador dará prioridade ao primeiro.

---

Outro caso especial é quando deseja-se utilizar `params` para vários tipos. Nesse caso, utiliza-se `object` ao invés do tipo específico.

Um exemplo é o seguinte:

```
public static void ImprimirLista(params object[] list)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(list[i] + " ");
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Que é aplicado assim:

```
ImprimirLista(10, "String", 20.4);
```

---

Quando se compara os métodos que usam `params` aos métodos que não usam `params`, deve-se considerar que o palavra-chave `params` é tratada pelo compilador de forma que quando se chama `Somar(2, 3, 4)`, o compilador transforma em `Somar(new int[]{2,3,4})`. Sem `params`, o compilador não fará essa consideração e exigirá que um `int[]`.

Por isso, a definição dos seguintes métodos resultarão em um conflito pois são equivalentes:

```
 public static void ImprimirLista(params int[] list) {}
 public static void ImprimirLista(int[] list) {}
```

Answer (score 5):

A resposta do Lucas Nunes está correta e bem completa. Só vou oferecer alternativas que podem ser úteis para outras pessoas hoje e no futuro.

É possível que não seja necessário ter um número de parâmetros completamente indeterminado. Você pode ter uma quantidade variável mas ter um limite máximo pequeno. E mais pode ser que cada parâmetros tenha um tipo diferente conhecido. Existem algumas alternativas nesses casos.

```
void M(int p1 = 1, string p2 = "", bool p3 = true, int p4 = 0) { ... }
```

Esta forma utiliza *optional arguments*. Então na chamada do método é possível usar apenas os parâmetros que não são iguais aos valores *default*. Ex.:

```
M(2); //na prática chama M(2, "", true, 0)
```

Além disso é possível usar a chamada através *named arguments*:

```
void M(p1: 1, p4: 0, p3: true)
```

Ainda há uma forma de passar parâmetros desta forma de forma explícita:

```
void M(Tuple<int, string, bool, int> p) { ... }
```

A chamada ficaria:

```
M(new Tuple<int, string, bool, int>(3, "teste", false, 1));
```

No C# também é possível:

```
M(new Tuple(3, "teste", false, 1));
```

Em algumas situações você pode não querer receber exatamente um *array*. Há propostas para usar um tipo enumerável, quase entrou no C# 6 e 7. Quem sabe no 8.

```
void M(params IEnumerable<int> p) { foreach(int i in p) Console.WriteLine(i); }
```

No [C# 7 tem tuplas na linguagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/195460/101) o que pode facilitar mais ainda:

```
void M((int valor, string nome, bool status, int outro) p) { ... }
```

A chamada ficaria:

```
M((3, "teste", false, 1));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/Tuple.cs).