# Significado de sinais em C#

Tags: c#, operadores, sintaxe

O que são os sinais  `< >`, `[ ]`, `{ }`,  `( )` fazendo jogo no Unity?

Comment: sugiro voce dar uma olha em logica de programação

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Isoladamente não servem para muita coisa, você precisa entender os contextos de cada uma.

Importante dizer que isso nada tem a ver com Unity que é só uma biblioteca, responderei sobre C#.

Todos esses são delimitadores assim como `''` e `""` são delimitadores de caractere e texto. Eles usam o mesmo caractere para iniciar e finalizar o texto. Outros delimitam de forma diferente.

Muitos deles tem funções e significam coisas diferentes dependendo do contexto que estão sendo usados.

`<>` delimita informações de parametrização de [*generics*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131890/101). Pode começar estudar em [Qual a diferença entre "generics" (Java/C#) e "template" (C++)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/150181/101) e [Quais as diferenças entre Tipos Genéricos em C# e em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10032/101). Depois falarei de outro par. Eles (chamados de *angle brackets*) funcionam como se fossem os parênteses de uma função, então ali tem parâmetros, mas aí é para tipos genéricos em vez de variáveis.

`[]` é usado como indicador de tipo *array* ou operador de uma coleção de dados onde dentro pode ir o índice de acesso ao elemento desejado (pode ser um pouco diferente disso, mas não vale a pena entrar em detalhes aqui). [Esse operador pode ser sobrecarregado em cada tipo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/341812/101). Quando é usado só para indicar um *array* dentro deles pode ter o tamanho dele.

Outro contexto que ele é usado é para delimitar [atributos personalizados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44900/101).

É chamado de *brackets* (colchetes).

`{}` é chamado de *braces* (chaves).

Pode ser usado para delimitar blocos de código em várias formas. Sempre que precisar ter vários [*statements*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173379/101) sendo tratados como uma coisa única precisa usá-las. Pode ser um bloco para unir ações que devem ser executadas condicionalmente após um `if`, `else`, ou uma repetição como o `while`, `for`, `foreach`, ou ainda em um `try` ou `catch` ou `finally`. Dá até para criar um bloco solto só para criar [escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) mesmo não estando associado a um comando desses.

Além disso serve para agrupar comandos de uma função, de uma classe ou outro tipo de dados ou até de um `namespace`. Em alguns deles só é obrigado usar se tiver mais que uma linha no bloco.

Também pode ser usado para inicializar alguns tipos de coleções de dados como os *arrays*, dicionários, listas e qualquer outra que tenha uma capacidade de ir adicionando elementos. Também serve como [inicializadores de objetos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/126348/101).

`()` é principalmente o operador de agrupamento de expressões. É igual a matemática, sabe? Só que na matemática tem colchetes e chaves também para dar uma diferenciação e uma certa importância entre eles, em programação não diferenciamos isso, vai colocando parênteses dentro de parênteses, os mais internos são os mais precedentes. Em C# não pode sobrecarregá-los.

Também pode ser usado como delimitador de parâmetros de função, mesmo que não tenha parâmetros precisa ter um par vazio para indicar que é uma função. O mesmo vale na chamada onde passa argumentos que devem estar entre eles ou se não tiver algum argumento devem estar vazios.

Outro contexto que ele é usado é para definir *tuplas*, que são estruturas compostas por 0 ou mais dados de tipos heterogêneos, é como se fosse uma `struct` mas de forma mais simples e sem ter um tipo nomeado explicitamente. Tem [exemplos no fim da minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14532/101).

Esqueci algum? Pode ser que depois de eu ter escrito isso alguns deles sejam usados em outros contextos.

Está confuso com tudo isso? Talvez o mais recomendado é aprender tudo de forma mais estruturada, e ver esses símbolos usados nos seus devidos contextos, com explicações mais detalhadas.